# Using a return value from a method

Tags: java, methods, return, instance-variables

I have a `Menu` class with a method that displays a menu, stores and then returns the selection made by the user.

```
public class Menu {

    public static int menuSelect(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello, Please Select A Function: ");
        System.out.println("1) Sort All Banks Alphabetically ");
        System.out.println("2) Calculate Interest And Show Balance ");
        System.out.println("3) Transfer Money ");
        System.out.println("4) Exit ");

        int Select = input.nextInt(); 

        return Select;   
   }
}
```

I want to use the return value in my main method but im not sure how. I have made an object in my main method by saying:

```
Menu menuObject = new Menu();
```

and by adding:

```
Menu.menuSelect();
```

I know that the menu runs but i want to get the return value from return Select in a variable in my main class. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You simply assign it to an `int`:

```
int result = Menu.menuSelect();
```

Notes:

- Follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) and name the variable `menu` instead (same for `select`)
- If the method is `static`, you can call from a *static* manner without constructing a *new* object
- If it's a *helper* method, and will be called only within the class itself, consider using another access modifier - `private`
- Indent your code for a better world

Comment: And perhaps what was meant was "Name the variable 'select' instead'."  Java naming conventions call for lower-case letters to start variable names.  'menuObject' is unusual, but doesn't violate naming conventions.  Also, study static and instance methods; there's nothing wrong with having menuSelect be static, as you have it, but you should know how to make it an instance method also.

Comment: that makes sense. I tend to get a bit inconsistant with variable names haha. fair enough i will look into that! thank you.